# Remove default value for a custom property in Advanced search

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm using Alfresco Share and I have a property with a default value

```
<property name="my:Property1">
     <title>Property1</title>
     <type>d:text</type>
     <multiple>true</multiple>
     <default>0</default>
</property>
```

I have customised the advanced search

```
<form id="search">
    <field-visibility>
        <show id="my:Property1"/>
    </field-visibility>
    <appearance>
        <field id="my:Property1" label-id="Property1">
    </appearance>
</form>
```

In Advanced search this property is initially filled with a default value, in my case with 0. Is there any way to remove that value from a search field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess in this case it's best to create a custom Share Form controller like the **textfield.ftl**.

In the default controller there is a freemarker entry `{field.value}`. Just remove this entry throughout the template and there won't be any default value shown.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.